# How to use local DNS in Pyppeteer

Tags: docker, dns, docker-compose, chromium, pyppeteer

I've got a reverse proxy, frontend and backend container. The backend is running [Pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer) and the reverse proxy is set up with an alias "servicename.localhost" in docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  default:
    aliases:
      - servicename.localhost
```

This way I'm able to `curl --insecure https://servicename.localhost` from the backend container, but unfortunately it seems Chromium on the same container ignores that setting and so "servicename.localhost" resolves to 127.0.0.1:

> pyppeteer.errors.PageError: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED at https://servicename.localhost/login

How can I work around this?

It looks like it may be related to [DNS prefetching](https://superuser.com/q/723703/2259) or [asynchronous DNS](https://superuser.com/q/646304/2259), but there doesn't seem to be a command line flag to disable either of them anymore.

Things I've tried which didn't change anything:

- Adding `"--host-rules='MAP servicename.localhost {}'".format(socket.gethostbyaddr('servicename.localhost')[-1][0])` to the `pyppeteer.launch` `args` list parameter.
- Adding `"--host-resolver-rules=[same as above]` to the `pyppeteer.launch` `args` list parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this by changing the TLD from "localhost" to "test".